# Putting a new XIB file in my project gives problems with "keys"

Tags: iphone, key, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to make a menu for my app which I already made. I added a new .m-file, .h-file & a nib file and named this Menu. Within my P-list i have set Menu as "Main nib file base name (iPad)".

When I run this project I get this error:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key opstelling."

Any suggestions how I can fix this error?

Comment: You should probably let us know what "opstelling" is. Some code would be very helpful.

Comment: Some code could get you somewhere

Comment: I couldn't find any referals to  "opstelling", so I just made an entire new project and loaded my menu at launch. It's working now with no errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your class instance (or reference if it is the file's owner) in your nib file by right-clicking it and see if there is no key "opstelling" being used there